# Passing textbox value to a function

Tags: c#, sql, function

I am having a problem with my login application. I am trying to get user type from the database based on username. When I pass the name from textbox user type will be null. Otherwise, when I declare the name manually it will work and gives the user type!!!

This is my code:

```
public string usertype { get { return label3.Text; } set { label3.Text = value; } }

public string username { get { return txtname.Text; } set { txtname.Text = value; } }

private void Login_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    username=txtname.Text;
    label3.Text=Users(username);
}

public string Users(string name)
{         
    using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection("Data Source=.;Initial Catalog=Stock;Integrated Security=True"))
    {
        string sql = "SELECT usertype FROM[dbo].[LoginTable] where UserName =@UserName";
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sql, con);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@UserName", name);
        con.Open();
        using (SqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader())
        {
            while (reader.Read())
            {                       
                usertype = reader["usertype"].ToString();

            }
            con.Close();
        }
    }
    return usertype;
}


//Main form to access user type for security

Login login = new Login();
string type=login.usertype; //-----usertype null
```

Note that I am accessing user type from `user_control` in the main form, don't know if it differs.

Comment: Have you tried adding breakpoints to debug your code?

Answer (score 0):

It works by changing the function location to the txtname_TextChanged event. Thanks all